# Adjusting height and width in DT::datatable R markdown

Tags: r, datatable, width, markdown

I'm trying to put a table in rmarkdown, using datatable command from DT package.
I have my table as pdf like :

[image]

which is not readable (very small) and it does not change if I add width/height="in px or %" in to the options list.

How could I get bigger table ?

````
```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!', echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
DT::datatable(cor()$AEP, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F,rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '100px')}")))


```
````

Comment: You can pass your `datatable` to `knitr::kable` and use the package `kableExtra` for styling; eg, `knitr::kable(dt) %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width=TRUE)`. See [the docs](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)

Comment: @juan The number of column are too much for that, I have tried your suggestion already, but since I could not break the rows into multi-line, they don't fit to the page width unless I choose very small font which again is not readable.

Comment: Ah, ok. Did you try `kable_styling(latex_options=scale_down)` instead of resizing it yourself?

Comment: @juan : Yes ! I did, but again this make the table very small ! If I could find a way that I could fix the column width and break the rows into multi lines it may help !

Comment: You can also adjust column width. On the other hand, you might consider using landscape mode for a very wide table.

Comment: Is it any update to this question? I try to adjust the height too for the output as a MS Word document